# Failing to change members of structs stored in two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a global two dimensional array holding a number of structs. From inside a function I try to change it's members like this:

```
struct ControlPin {
    int pin;
    int previousValue;
};

ControlPin controls[CHANNELS][MULTIPLEXERS];

void readControlInput(int channel, int multiplexer) {
    ControlPin control = controls[channel][multiplexer];
    control.previousValue = analogRead(control.pin);
}
```

If i print out control.previousValue inside readControlInput() I can verify that it has changed, but after getting out of the function scope, the change is gone. How can I get a reference to the struct instead of copying it? I assume that's what happening, but I cant see why. I know that when you pass a value as a parameter to a function it is actually a copy, but here I'm accessing the global array directly?

I'm used to Java so this is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: For example by `readControlInput(int, int, ControlPin &control)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java all objects are (IIRC) references. In C++ the default is that objects are *values*. When you do

```
ControlPin control = controls[channel][multiplexer];
```

you *copy* the "value" in `controls[channel][multiplexer]`, then when you modify `control` you only modify the local value, and not the value in the array.

The simplest option is to explicitly say that `control` is a reference, by using the ampersand (`&`) when declaring the variable:

```
ControlPin& control = controls[channel][multiplexer];
//        ^
//        |
// Note ampersand here
```

That tells the compiler that `control` is a *reference* and then initializes it to reference the object (value) at `controls[channel][multiplexer]`.

---

On an unrelated not, C++ have no bounds-checking. If you access an array out of bounds the compiler will happily allow it, but it will lead to *undefined behavior* at run-time. You need to do bounds-checking yourself if you want to avoid weird problems. It doesn't have to be in the function, but it needs to be done somewhere.

Comment: Ok, so If I do controls[channel][multiplexer].previousValue = 5 it would change the original value?

Comment: A follow-up question on the bounds-checking comment: If I have declared an int array[10] and haven't initialized it, can I check the indexes for undefined before trying to access them?

Comment: @LoveAurell Uninitialized local (and non-static) variables have an *indeterminate* value, doing just about anything (except initializing them) will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

You're not accessing the array directly, this works exactly like if you had passed the element to a function:

```
void readInput(ControlPin control)
{
     control.previousValue = analogRead(control.pin);   
}

void readControlInput(int channel, int multiplexer) {
    readInput(controls[channel][multiplexer]);
}
```

You can tell from the types - `ControlPin` means the same thing regardless of whether it is a local variable or a parameter.

In C++, variables that contain class instances always contain class instances and not some kind of "reference" to them, so just like when calling a function,

```
ControlPin control = controls[channel][multiplexer];
```

creates a *copy* of the array element, and

```
control.previousValue = analogRead(control.pin);
```

modifies that copy.

The simplest fix is to write it in one line:

```
controls[channel][multiplexer].previousValue = analogRead(control.pin);
```

You can also use a reference variable (which is different from Java's "references") to refer to the array element itself:

```
ControlPin& control = controls[channel][multiplexer];
control.previousValue = analogRead(control.pin);
```

This is most useful if you need to do more than one thing with the same element - it's both more readable and more resilient to errors than duplicating the indexing.